# Is there any way to access window shell by secureCRT program?

Tags: secure-crt

I'm using window10 and secureCRT program.
secureCRT is better to use than window cmd prompt so I want to access window shell by secureCRT program.

Anybody knows how to I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can either map your key or create a button to launch Windows Command Prompt.
Do let me know if these two solutions works for you.

1. Go under **Tools** → **Keymap Editor** → **Map a Key...** → (*map a key/keystroke*) → Toggle the drop down under **Function** and Select "**Launch Application**"

Paste in "**C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe**"

OR

2. Go under **View** → turn on **Button Bar** → **Right Click** any free space within the **Button Bar** → **New Button...** → Toggle the drop down under **Function** and Select "**Launch Application**"

Paste in "**C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe**"